# Nativescript-audio not working on iOS device

Tags: ios, nativescript, audio-recording

I've used this plugin to record audio and play recorded audio.
https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-audio
When I build both iOS and Android platforms, it works well on Android but don't work on iOS. I've tried to clone demo project and run. but ...

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For new googlers

First install : `ns plugin add @akylas/nativescript-audio`

Then add `sessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` to player options

Example:

```
const player = new TNSPlayer();
const playerOptions = {
    audioFile: '~/assets/audio.mp3',
    loop: true,
    autoPlay: true,
    sessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback // I just added this to make it work with that package
};

player.playFromFile(playerOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I resolved it by using a previous version of the package. 
In my packages.json file I changed the line to

```
    "nativescript-audio": "~3.0.0"
```

I hope this helps